# 1980's or early 90's children's book about a girl who was a clone of a scientist

Tags: story-identification, clones, childrens-novel

I'm looking for the title of a book I read in the mid 90's, but it may have been older. It was about a girl who was a clone of a female scientist who had died before her research was completed.

She lived with a family who knew her secret and there was some future technology similar to Google Maps that would warn her not to go to certain parts of the city because of riots but it was really to keep her from running into her clones.

I remember a part of the book saying that the clone experiment was a failure because all the girls grew up with different talents and interests.

I don't know if it was a standalone book or part of a series but it kind of haunts me and I would love to revisit it.

Comment: Not sure if this question is after the same book as you, but it made yours me think of it: [Novel About a Girl Who Realizes She is a Clone](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10478/1234)

Comment: A search lead me to this site from that question... But, not the same book.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sure there's more than one book that would fit this general description, but it sounds to me like "Anna to the Infinite Power", by Mildred Ames.  I never read the book, but I saw the movie it was based on once on cable, and your description sounds just like it.  The book was published in 1981, and was for teens.  At the time, I was interested because I was looking for stories that had inspired X-Files episodes, and this one seems to have been a direct influence on the first season episode "Eve"--which took the idea in a very different direction.

Interesting that now we've got a TV series about cloned girls running into each other from the BBC--"Orphan Black".  Haven't seen it yet.  That idea keeps popping up again and again across the decades.  I guess because we're still not sure how we feel about the idea of cloning humans, which for all we know has already happened.   And because it's a way of examining the nature of human identity.

(editing)

I read up a bit on the book, and I'm sure it's the one you were looking for.  Quite different from the film adaptation, which is set in the present day, not in a dystopian future.  But still similar enough that I recognized the story from your description.

Comment: That's it, thanks!

Comment: Glad to have been of help--I only just showed up here last week, to try and identify a book I read a long time ago--which someone did in fact identify--and it's nice to be able to do that favor for someone else.  Take a penny, leave a penny.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it was the third book of the Watchers series, *[I.D.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007DFUQUE)*

> When her parents tell her that she is adopted, Eve is upset but not surprised. After all, she doesn’t look like her parents, and has always felt a strange distance from them. But as she approaches her fourteenth birthday, something begins to feel very wrong. While skiing, she sees a girl about her age die suddenly of a heart attack. A few days later, Eve learns that the girl’s sudden death is part of a pattern of fourteen-year-olds dying of strange causes, based on a chromosomal defect. One of the dead is Alexis, a girl who looks exactly like Eve.
>
> Eve tracks down Alexis’s parents, hoping she has finally found her real family—but it turns out Alexis was adopted too. Something is killing fourteen-year-old children, and finding out where she comes from is the only way for Eve to save herself.

[image: Book Cover - Watchers - I.D.]

Comment: The comments on your previous answer still apply: the actual book was found four years ago (see the accepted answer above), and it wasn't this one either. However, your answer(s) could still be good if you **[edit] to explain why the books you mention fit the description given in the question**. Just saying "I think it was this one" doesn't help future readers, but describing the plot and explaining how it fits the question could be useful to other people looking for this book.

Answer (score 1):

*[Replica](https://www.goodreads.com/series/60766-replica)*, a book series by one Marilyn Kaye, essentially revolves around a 13 clone model of the *Orphan Black* plotline (just for reference), but predates it by approximately 15 years. Not sure if this is what you’re looking for, but the concepts seem to line up pretty well.

Here's the Goodreads summary for the first book in the series, *[Amy, Number Seven](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1071338.Amy_Number_Seven)* (1998).

> Amy Candler is the perfect 12-year-old girl. She can do anything. She knows everything. But Amy doesn't have all the answers to the mystery of her past. All she knows is that her recurring nightmares seem so real. That her crescent-shaped birthmark wasn't there yesterday. That a strange man is taking photos of her. That her mother is acting weird. That someone is sending her anonymous warnings to keep her talents a secret. Slowly Amy is piecing together her identity, but she'd better hurry.

Comment: The person who asked the question already [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/33278/122024) eight years ago -- as denoted by the green tick to the left of that answer --which suggests that your answer is unlikely to be correct.

Comment: Regardless of the correctness of your answer, welcome to Sci-Fi and Fantasy, please take our [tour], refer to the [help] as and when for guidance as to our ways. Enjoy the site.

Comment: @LogicDictates - it is indeed clear that it is not the answer (as you mentioned, there is an accepted answer, *and* there is a link to a question where "Replica" is the answer (see comments on the question) and the user commented that it is not the book.  On the other hand, perhaps this answer could help someone else, looking for a similar book...