# Book about girl who learn she's a clone?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

There was a young adult/teenage book I read a few years ago, something along the lines of a teenage girl who lives in a time when clones are considered extinct and any surviving ones are considered dangerous terrorists. Then, she learns that she is a clone, that her closest family/friends also knew, but kept it secret to protect her until she was ready. I remember the Underground Railroad had something to do with it.
It was the first in a series of books.

Does anyone know what this book or the series is titled? I tried to Google it but couldn't find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Novel About a Girl Who Realizes She is a Clone](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10478/novel-about-a-girl-who-realizes-she-is-a-clone)

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is a dupe. The linked question seems to have more than one clone (twins etc) and there's talks about some scientific project and a crescent shaped birthmark.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102152/sci-fi-book-featuring-a-race-called-the-os (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

## The Clone Codes

> In the year 2170 an underground abolitionist movement fights for the freedom of cyborgs and clones, who are treated no better than slaves
>
> The Cyborg Wars are over and Earth has peacefully prospered for more than one hundred years. Yet sometimes history must repeat itself until humanity learns from its mistakes. In the year 2170, despite technological and political advances, cyborgs and clones are treated no better than slaves, and an underground abolitionist movement is fighting for freedom. Thirteen-year-old Leanna's entire life is thrown into chaos when The World Federation of Nations discovers her mom is part of the radical Liberty Bell Movement.

[GoodReads Description](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6666385-the-clone-codes)

> Clone Codes by The McKissacks is about a girl named Leanna Deberry in the year 2170. She attends virtual school with the help of virtual reality type glasses in which she get to experience history as though she were really there. But as she learns about slavery and the Underground Railroad in school, she learns about another type of slavery in her real life that involves clones and cyborgs.

[Barnes and Noble's user review by Jenny_Rose](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/clone-codes-patricia-c-mckissack/1102492386?ean=9781613832417)

Comment: This seems very likely

Comment: Did they call them the Cyborg Wars because they could not call them the Clone Wars?

Comment: @Adamant, I don't know. not sure that has anything to do with the question either...

Answer (score 5):

## Replica (*series*)

### Amy, Number 7

looks like Marilyn Kaye wrote a series of books about 13 girls that were cloned. looks like "Amy, Number 7" is the first in the series

[Wikipedia has this to say about the first book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marilyn_Kaye):

> Whilst writing an autobiography for an English project, Amy begins to question the identity of her "father", who supposedly died before she was born. She is also confused by her suddenly increased physical abilities and powers of healing. She is shocked to discover that she is one of thirteen clones created in a government project which her "mother" was part of.

Comment: No, it's not this one, it sounds similar, but I do remember something about the Underground Railroad? Don't know if that helps any.