# Part of trilogy, race called The O's, and clone rights trial

Tags: story-identification, novel, clones

I'm looking for a novel I read when I was younger. It was the third of a trilogy. It featured clones and a benevolent alien race known as "The O's". At some point, there is a big clone rights trial where an American revolutionary war figure (possibly Ben Franklin) acts as a lawyer or something. There was a futuristic battle. At the end, the O's show up after being built up the entire book.

Over all, I remember the story as being anti-climatic and disappointing.

Does anyone know what book this is?

It is not "Slaves of the Legion."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[**The Clone Codes**](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6666385-the-clone-codes)* by Patricia & John McKissack

The Goodreads review of the story contains numerous references to clones (duh), clone rights, virtual avatars of various famous abolitionists and a benevolent alien species called "The O":

> In the year 2170 an underground abolitionist movement fights for the
>   freedom of cyborgs and clones, who are treated no better than slaves
>
> The Cyborg Wars are over and Earth has peacefully prospered for more
>   than one hundred years. Yet sometimes history must repeat itself until
>   humanity learns from its mistakes. In the year 2170, despite
>   technological and political advances, cyborgs and clones are treated
>   no better than slaves, and an underground abolitionist movement is
>   fighting for freedom. Thirteen-year-old Leanna's entire life is thrown
>   into chaos when The World Federation of Nations discovers her mom is
>   part of the radical Liberty Bell Movement.

...

> With the help of some virtual “Custodians” (Ben Franklin & Eleanor
>   Roosevelt & others), Leanna learns some harsh truths about the world
>   she lives in.

...

> The entire thing with the O seemed to have been pulled from a cheesy
>   scifi movie and made the plot way to complex.

Comment: Making it a double? :-o Why not just edit the first answer? (because this way you get double the rep, of course)

Comment: @randal'thor - Because the first answer is flat out wrong, but could serve as a useful pointer for future searches. If I go for a double-answer and the OP doesn't actually say "this is the right one" and mark it as accepted, there's no useful way for a visitor to determine which was the correct answer. If I delete it or overwrite it then there's no useful pointer. It's not always about rep, my friend.

Comment: Yes, book 3 of the Clone Codes is the one I remembered! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A quick google suggests this is "[Slave of the Legion](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Slave-Legion-3-Soldier/dp/1484886569)", the third part of the 'Soldier of the Legion' trilogy.

> The O's had killed two billion humans. Beta Three wanted revenge. The
>   Mound was in his sights.
>
> "There's no way the O's are going to inherit this world. It's going to
>   glow in the dark first." When squad Beta is sent on a recon mission to
>   Uldo in the Gassies, they find the Omni's--deadly aliens with
>   unstoppable psychic power loose in the wrong universe. In a snowy
>   landscape they discover the Mound, a massive, mysterious structure
>   built by the O's. Approaching, they find the way lined with the
>   impaled bodies of innocent humans.

Comment: It's not that but thanks. I remember the O's in my story as being beneficial to mankind, not harmful. I'll update my answer.