# Looking for a series about young girl who was created in a lab by her mum

Tags: story-identification

I'm not sure exactly when these were published, but at least ten years or more.

The main character discovers she is perfect and was created in a lab by her mum, who is actually the scientist who created her.

Throughout the series, people try to capture her. She then finds out that she has brothers and sisters created like her.

Not sure how many books were in the series either. It's a series for young readers (my friend read them around age 10) and would have been published no later than 2010.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We could use a bit more info here; check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/101407) for asking good story-id questions to see if they help you recall anything else you can add.  For example do you remember what any of the covers look like?

Comment: No. This is a series described to me by a friend, but she couldn't remember anything else specific. Not names or places either, really. Just that she read them when she was around ten years old. So I know they were not recently published. At the latest, they would have been published around 2010. Sorry, I don't have more. Looking for them for a young reader.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Orphan Black if you prefer a TV series.

Comment: This seems like it would describe many series. Do you remember more specific details? When you say “her mum,” does that mean it was set in Britain?

Comment: The webcomic Naronic? The main character, Helen B. Narbon, is her mother's clone. The B stands for beta. http://www.narbonic.com/

Comment: @Davislor I'm not sure it was set in the U.K., my friend is from New Zealand. So, it could be something set in Australia or New Zealand too. Sorry to be such a pain everyone **shrugs** but you guys are great! Thanks for all the great info.

Comment: @NomadMaker I bet she'd love this for her daughter!! Thanks

Comment: @CarlWitthoft my friend is looking for something for her daughter, but Jacinda might like it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might be Marilyn Kaye's *[Replica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marilyn_Kaye#Replica)* series (I borrowed from my answer to [Identifying a super-soldier novel with half-moon symbol](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/158032/23243)).

> "Replica" is a children's science fiction series about Amy Candler, a young teenager who discovers she is one of thirteen cloned girls who have been genetically modified to have superhuman abilities. She was created in the government-funded Project Crescent, and was kidnapped and adopted by one of the scientists after a change of heart. Throughout the series Amy struggles to live a normal life as the mysterious Organisation tries to use her and the other Project Crescent clones to create a master race and take over the world. Amy also seeks to help the other clones in the project, and encounters a number of other children and teenagers with genetic modifications or supernatural powers.

Amy is indeed a clone, the result of a super-soldier project. She essentially has peak human capabilities including extreme strength and speed, and the ability to pick up skills rapidly. In particular, Amy's abilities develop in the first book in her practice of gymnastics. As per your description, her mother rescued her when the facility burned out (implied to be sabotage whether by researchers, rivals, or Project Crescent itself) and Amy finds that there are more girls like her out there. Within the first two books, she meets one who is a French ballerina and one who is a minor movie star. She does have non-powered friends in her school.

It looks like books 6 and 12 deal with "Andy", who was genetically engineered to be her "perfect match", with more "Andies" showing up in the 18th book. That may be who you are remembering as her "brothers" since they were created in the lab in a similar manner at the same time.

Comment: This actually sounds like a better match for OP's description than the currently higher answer.

Comment: I have to ask her about this. She said the main character found out she had brothers and sisters, so I'm not sure if this fits. But you could be right about her being mistaken. I'll check with her. Thanks bunches!!

Comment: @user150571: She meets a new clone in almost every book (and later starts meeting clones of Andy, who was, I think, grown at the same lab). :) At the very least, her other clones are as much her sisters as any identical twin, sharing the same initial genetics (identical twins, of course, can diverge in some genes if mutated at an early stage, and can experience different environmental factors).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots : You were right on target. She said that was the one. Thanks!!

Answer (score 11):

Possibly "MILA 2.0" by Debra Driza (2013) and at least two sequels.  From a review on Goodreads:

> Sixteen year-old Mila believed she was a human living in a small town
> with her ‘mother’ after the death of her ‘father’ and was never meant
> to find out that she was an android, built in a science lab and kept
> hidden to avoid not only the person who helped create her but another
> group intent on using her for her abilities.

I have read only the first book.  It fits your description well enough for Mila herself. I do not recall any siblings being mentioned explicitly, but from the back story it was certainly possible that there were some.  They could well have been introduced in a sequel. There is a prequel short story "Origins: The Fire" that is available as a free Kindle download on Amazon.

Comment: My friend said it wasn't this series, but she's now put it on her 'to be read' list. So thanks so much!!